# Python script leaves the database in restoring mode

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, python

I am attempting to use python to automate some of our database restores.  When I run the SQL query the database restores and comes back up like normal, but when I run the python script that uses the same SQL query the database is left in the restoring mode.

Any help with what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pyodbc

#Set these Variables
sourceserver = 'MySourceServerName'
destinationserver = 'MyDestinationServerName'
dbname = 'test'


sourceserverplusport = sourceserver + ',1433'
destinationserverplusport = destinationserver + ',1433'


def ExecSQL(serverplusport, dbnameIN, sql):
    try:
        connexecsql = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                                         'Server=' + serverplusport +';'
                                         'Database=' + dbnameIN + ';'
                                         'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

        #Set AutoCommit
        if connexecsql is not None:
           connexecsql.autocommit = True
       
        print(sql)
        cursor = connexecsql.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)
    finally:    
        cursor.commit
        cursor.close
        connexecsql.commit
        connexecsql.close


sqlcommand = r"""IF @@SERVERNAME = 'MyDestinationServerName'
RESTORE DATABASE test FROM DISK = '\\MyBackupPath\test.BAK' WITH FILE = 1, MOVE N'test' to N'X:\Database\MDF\test.mdf',  MOVE N'test_log' to N'Y:\Database\LDF\test_log.ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE, RECOVERY, STATS = 5;"""

ExecSQL(destinationserverplusport, "master", sqlcommand)
```

If I add one more `ExecSQL` command at the end of the script to run `RESTORE DATABASE test WITH RECOVERY;` at the end returns the error:

> The database cannot be recovered because the log was not restored."

Including the `REPLACE` with the `RECOVERY` removes the error but leaves the database in restoring still.

Answer (score 5):

Pyodbc won't progress past info messages automatically, and RESTORE generates a lot of them. So you must process them with `cursor.nextset()` or else you're actually aborting the RESTORE by running `cursor.close()` before it actually completes.

Eg

```
cursor.execute(sql)
while cursor.nextset():
    pass 
cursor.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using https://dbatools.io/ instead?

It's FREE and highly regarded.

Check out https://docs.dbatools.io/#Restore-DbaDatabase.

No disrespect to Python intended.